# How to change PGN Viewer board orientation to perspective of side not-to-move?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, pgn-viewer

How can I change the PGN Viewer's board orientation to the perspective of the side that is not to move?

Is the orientation determined only by the active color field of the FEN notation? If so, then is the board's orientation always from the perspective of the side that is to move? If so, and given the board is unlabeled, would that make it impossible to determine if the board is from White's perspective with White-to-move or Black's perspective with Black-to-move in a move-less diagram (or even the replayer without copying the move text or visual cues like pawn movement), unless it can be inferred from relative locations of the pieces alone? If so, then is the only way to show the board from the perspective of the side-not-to-move to change the active color? That is a bad hack because anyone trying to copy the position text would copy it incorrectly; and if there were any moves, they would be mismatched to the position by a half-move. I'd like as new features rank and file labels and the ability to change the board orientation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to view the game from black's perspective, you can add the tag `[StartFlipped "1"]` to the pgn headers.  Similarly, if you want to force white to be on the bottom even though black is moving first, you can add `[StartFlipped "0"]` to the headers and it will override the default of the side to move on the bottom.